# How to avoid no such table error Django db

Tags: python, django

Using django python, I come across this error whenever I want to clone the repository, and so I assume its whenever it creates a new database (the database is on .gitignore). I know its an issue regarding the models, but I have no idea how to fix it. Its not an issue for me as of right now, but will be if I move to production.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blogger_postcategory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 446, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 625, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/blog/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('', include('blogger.urls')),
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/blogger/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/blogger/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import EditForm, PostForm
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/blogger/forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class PostForm(forms.Form):
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/blogger/forms.py", line 23, in PostForm
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices = tuplelistmaker(list(PostCategory.objects.all())))
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/rayyanshikoh/Documents/GitHub/shaista-s-cooking-blog/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blogger_postcategory
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelState
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.

Status = (
    (0, 'Draft'),
    (1, 'Publish')
)

Featured = (
    (0, 'Featured'),
    (1, 'Default')
)

class FeaturedYTVideo(models.Model):
    video = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.video

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categorySlug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'blog_posts')
    short_description = models.TextField()
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status, default=0)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'coverimages', null =True, blank = True)
    captioned_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'captionedimages', null=True, blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    featured = models.IntegerField(choices=Featured, default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(PostCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    embedded_code = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='null')
    tags = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The only way I have been able to fix this is by deleting the database, commenting out the Post model, creating a PostCategory object, and then uncommenting the Post model.

Comment: You have to apply the migrations after clone the repository

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in the post, this error occurs when i run makemigrations and even migrate